# Creating multiple charts based on dictionary length

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, chart.js

I am building a dashboard website for some water quality sensors I have that send the information as an API in JSON format. The plan is to create real-time charts using that data using chart.js and django. Right now I am turning the JSON file to dictionaries like so:

```
JSON file: 
{
  "11:00:00 AM": {
    "Temperatura": 30,
    "pH": 7.1,
    "Conductividad": 759,
    "Cloro Residual": 1.1,
    "Turbidez": 0,
    "Color": "<5",
    "pH de la Det de color": 7.12,
    "Solidos totales": 512,
    "S�lidos disueltos": 494,
    "S�lidos suspendidos totales": 0,
    "Dureza total como CaCO3": 227.24,
    "Alcalinidad como CaCO3": 227.7,
    "Cloruros": 64.02,
    "Fluoruros": 0.91,
    "Nitrogeno Amoniacal": 0,
    "Nitrogeno de nitritos": 0,
    "Nitrogeno de nitratos": 4.47,
    "Sulfatos": 37.27,
    "Sustancias activas al azul de metileno": 0,
    "Fenoles": 0,
    "Coliformes totales": 0,
    "Aluminio": 0,
    "Arsenico": 0.015,
    "Bario": 0.1784,
    "Calcio": 79.7,
    "Cadmio": 0,
    "Cromo": 0.0085,
    "Cobre": 0,
    "Fierro": 0.0327,
    "Potasio": 12.18,
    "Magnesio": 13.37,
    "Manganeso": 0,
    "Sodio": 55.75,
    "Plomo": 0,
    "Zinc": 0,
    "Mercurio": 0
  },
```

I am then turning them to dictionaries with all of the values like so:

```
    ['11:00:00 AM', '11:10:05 AM', '11:20:10 AM', '11:30:14 AM', '11:40:19 AM', '11:50:24 AM', '12:00:29 PM', '12:10:34 PM', '12:20:38 PM', '12:30:43 PM', '12:40:48 PM', '12:50:53 PM', '01:00:58 PM', '01:11:03 PM', '01:21:07 PM', '01:31:07 PM']
[[30, 30, 28, 29, 19, 0, 0, 29, 31, 33, 27, 29, 27, 29, 30, 30], [7.1, 7.6, 7.5, 7.4, 7.5, 5, 8.5, 7.7, 7.2, 7.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.3, 7.7, 7.7, 7.7], [759, 899, 869, 898, 833, '0', '', 841, 862, 826, 861, 896, 857, 836, 864, 864], [1.1, 0.7, 1, 0.3, 1.1, '0', 1.5, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '0', 20, '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5', '<5'], [7.12, 7.47, 7.4, 7.38, 7.42, '0', '', 7.58, 7.74, 7.53, 7.7, 7.45, 7.52, 7.55, 7.58, 7.58], [512, 598, 584, 599, 564, '0', '', 579, 576, 558, 586, 596, 593, 583, 569, 569], [494, 586, 562, 568, 530, '0', 1000, 538, 566, 550, 576, 564, 530, 558, 532, 532], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [227.24, 319.47, 296, 301.54, 263.56, '0', 500, 278.62, 292, 261.31, 298, 295.51, 300, 294.54, 279.54, 279.54], [227.7, 229.2, 222.1, 246.8, 213.4, '0', '', 232.6, 227.7, 224.8, 225.6, 44.2, 226.7, 225.4, 225.6, 225.6], [64.02, 112.16, 107, 111.17, 102.07, '0', 250, 93.69, 99.12, 91.32, 104.05, 106.7, 101.58, 96.16, 101.58, 101.58], [0.91, 0.9, 0.98, 0.94, 0.96, '0', 1.5, 1.07, 0.97, 1, 0.91, 0.94, 0.83, 0.88, 0.92, 0.92], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4.47, 4.21, 4.49, 4.51, 4.76, '0', 10, 4.01, 3.91, 3.96, 3.96, 4.67, 4.17, 3.94, 4.59, 4.59], [37.27, 43.75, 43.91, 43.33, 41.2, '0', 400, 43.39, 43.67, 42.1, 39.94, 46.48, 44.58, 42.52, 45.06, 45.06], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.015, 0.0128, 0.0121, 0.0137, 0.0147, '0', 0.05, 0.0147, 0.014, 0.0136, 0.0134, 0.0135, 0.0139, 0.0145, 0.0152, 0.0152], [0.1784, 0.192, 0.1893, 0.1783, 0.2004, '0', 0.7, 0.1913, 0.1741, 0.1762, 0.1716, 0.1763, 0.1749, 0.1906, 0.2021, 0.2021], [79.7, 102, 80.42, 93.63, 97.76, '0', '', 108.9, 84.7, 83.81, 82.5, 91.71, 86.72, 105.9, 103, 103], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0085, 0.0043, 0.0049, 0.0077, 0.0088, '0', 0.05, 0.0073, 0.0065, 0.0073, 0.0063, 0.0078, 0.0066, 0.0071, 0.0097, 0.0097], [0, 0.0851, 0, 0.0075, 0, '0', 2, 0, 0.0623, 0.0071, 0.0102, 0.0112, 0.12, 0, 0, 0], [0.0327, 0, 0, 0, 0.0364, '0', 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.043, 0.043], [12.18, 11.9, 10.32, 11.51, 13.19, '0', '', 12.43, 10.58, 11.59, 10.28, 11.34, 10.86, 12.23, 13.27, 13.27], [13.37, 18.03, 15.31, 16.42, 17.23, '0', '', 15.85, 17.71, 14.72, 14.35, 16.03, 14.98, 15.6, 17.13, 17.13], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [55.75, 56.45, 48.75, 54.63, 58.86, '0', 200, 52.8, 48.68, 53.42, 47.29, 53.85, 49.52, 52.47, 59.05, 59.05], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.0561, 0, 0, 0, '0', 5, 0, 0, 0.0394, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0]]
```

In my views page I am sending all of that information to the HTML where chart.js creates the charts using that data.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
import json

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'charts.html', {})


def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return JsonResponse(data)


class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        with open("file.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            labels_list = list(data)
            a = list(data.values())[0]
            filename = 'param_'
            counter1 = 1
            counter2 = 2
            parameters = {}
            for x in range(len(a.values())):
                counter1 = str(counter1)
                full_name = (filename + counter1)
                counter1 = counter2
                counter2 += 1
                full_values = []
                for i in data:
                    v = labels_list.index(i)
                    aaa = list(data.values())[v]
                    val = list(aaa.values())[x]
                    full_values.append(val)
                parameters[full_name] = full_values
        labels = list(data)
        name_param = list(a)
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "values": list(parameters.values()),
            "name_param": name_param,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

My problem is in creating the charts, right now I am having to manually create the canvas, give them their ID, create new context for them and their respective data.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var labels =  []
var values = []
var name_param = []

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        values = data.values
        name_param = data.name_param
        console.log(data)
        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
function setChart(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
                var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2');
                var ctx3 = document.getElementById('myChart3');
                var ctx4 = document.getElementById('myChart4');
                var ctx5 = document.getElementById('myChart5');
                var ctx6 = document.getElementById('myChart6');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx6, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[5],
                            data: values[5],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx5, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[4],
                            data: values[4],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx4, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[3],
                            data: values[3],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx3, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[2],
                            data: values[2],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[1],
                            data: values[1],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name_param[0],
                            data: values[0],
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    }

                })
}
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12' url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}'>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart3" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart4" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart5" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="myChart6" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

My question is if there is a way to maybe have a for loop that creates the chart for every parameter. Or how will you suggest creating multiple charts?

Comment: Hi there, looks like you haven't given any response on the answer below. Could you let me know if it helped you out?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your data I think that you could start by improving the structure of your data. The reason for this is that the data is the only thing that is different with each chart. So tuning the data to the need of the chart is a great way to make it easier for the frontend to create your charts.

The `values` and `name_param` lists are both separate, but they are both linked by their indexes. This could be improved by makes `name_param` / `value` groups in a new dictionary. And naming the properties to mirror the settings of the `Chart` instance will even better, like `label` and `data`.

Try to modify your list to the following structure.

```js
{
  labels: [], // Labels remains unchanged.
  datasets: [ // New array with objects.
    {
      label: '', // previously known as name_param
      data: '' // previously known as value
    },
    {
      label: '',
      data: ''
    },
    // ... etc.
  ]
}
```

This enables you to easily loop over each group in the `dataset` property and create a new chart for each set. But first you'll need some helper functions that create the `<div>`, `<canvas>` and `Chart` instances.

First the `<div>` and `<canvas>`. The function below creates both the bootstrap column and the canvas element which will be placed inside the DOM.

```
function createCanvasAndColumn() {
  const column = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('col-sm-4');

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;

  column.append(canvas);
 
  /** 
   * Return both the canvas and the column.
   * The column is needed to append to the row.
   * The canvas is needed to create a chart with.
   */
  return { canvas, column };
}
```

We don't need an `id` attribute as we have a reference to the element already in the `canvas` constant. The canvas will be appended to the `<div>`. It then returns an object with a reference to the column (which we need to add to the document) and a reference to the canvas (which we need for the `Chart` instance).

Now for creating the charts. I've kept the changed data structure suggested at the beginning of the answer in mind as how the data should appear in your application, so the following function uses that structure.

```
const chartsRow = document.getElementById('charts-row');

function createCharts({ labels, datasets }) {
  /**
   * Loop over each item in datasets and create a
   * new chart for each item. Each chart is then returned
   * resulting in an array of Chart instances.
   */
  const charts = datasets.map((dataset) => {
    const { canvas, column } = createCanvasAndColumn();

    const chart = new Chart(canvas, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          ...dataset,
          fill: false
        }]
      }
    });

    // Add column (and canvas) to the row.
    chartsRow.append(column);
    return chart;
  });

  /**
   * Return the charts array. This is not mandatory,
   * but it might come in handy if you'd need to access
   * the Chart instances at some point.
   */
  return charts;
}
```

This `createCharts` function expects an object with a `labels` and `dataset` key. It loops over the `datasets` array to create a canvas element per set. That canvas element will then be used to create a new `Chart` instance. The `name` and `value` of each dataset will be used to set the data of that `Chart` instance.

You may have noticed that the loop is done with `map`. This will loop over each item in the array and expects a `return` statement for each item. This will result in a new array being created based on the returned values inside the loop. The `charts` constant will actually be an array of `Chart` instances.

Now with these functions in place all you'd have to do is pass the data you've received from your Django application into the `createCharts` function to build the charts.

Make your row easy to select by adding an `id` attribute. This attribute should have a unique value. In the `createCharts` snippet above the element is being selected from the document to append the charts with.

```
<div class='row' id="charts-row">
  <div class='col-sm-12' url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}'>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

From here you call your request and pass the data to your `createCharts` function, which then loops over the data and creates a chart for each item.

```
const endpoint = '/api/chart/data/';

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data) {
    createCharts(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(textStatus);
  }
})
```